# Distribution of time periods over rows with certain status (column value)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe containing logs, with each row corresponding to the state of the system at the time it is logged, and a group number. I would like to find the lengths of the time periods for which each group is in an unhealthy state.

For example, if this were my table:

```
TIMESTAMP | STATUS_CODE | GROUP_NUMBER
--------------------------------------
02:03:11  | healthy     | 000001
02:03:04  | healthy     | 000001
02:03:03  | unhealthy   | 000001
02:03:00  | unhealthy   | 000001
02:02:58  | healthy     | 000008
02:02:57  | healthy     | 000008
02:02:55  | unhealthy   | 000001
02:02:54  | healthy     | 000001
02:02:50  | healthy     | 000007
02:02:48  | healthy     | 000004
```

I would want to return Group 000001 having an unhealthy time period of 9 seconds (from 02:02:55 to 02:03:04).

Other groups could also have unhealthy time periods, and I would want to return those as well.

Due to the possibility of consecutive rows with the same status, and since rows of different groups are interspersed, I am struggling to find a way to do this efficiently.

I cannot convert the Pyspark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe, as it is much too large.

How can I efficiently determine the lengths of these time periods?

Thanks so much!

Comment: did any of the posted solution worked?

Comment: @rogue-one - thanks, your implementation was very well-explained and detailed! Walking through the steps, it seems quite brilliant and clever. 
An extension of this - is there a way to get the length of each time period for which a group is in the unhealthy state (e.g. if Group 000001 has multiple periods of unhealthy state, return the length of each)?

Comment: if you do a `t2.timestamp_value - t1.timestamp_value` without the sum and group by in my query, you should be able to get the duration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pyspark with spark-sql solution would look like this.

First we create the sample data-set. In addition to the dataset we generate row_number field partition on group and order by the timestamp. then we register the generated dataframe as a table say `table1`

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp

df = spark.createDataFrame([
('2017-01-01 02:03:11','healthy','000001'),
('2017-01-01 02:03:04','healthy','000001'),
('2017-01-01 02:03:03','unhealthy','000001'),
('2017-01-01 02:03:00','unhealthy','000001'),
('2017-01-01 02:02:58','healthy','000008'),
('2017-01-01 02:02:57','healthy','000008'),
('2017-01-01 02:02:55','unhealthy','000001'),
('2017-01-01 02:02:54','healthy','000001'),
('2017-01-01 02:02:50','healthy','000007'),
('2017-01-01 02:02:48','healthy','000004')
],['timestamp','state','group_id'])

df = df.withColumn('rownum', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(df.group_id).orderBy(unix_timestamp(df.timestamp))))

df.registerTempTable("table1")
```

once the dataframe is registered as a table (`table1`). the required data can be computed as below using spark-sql

```
>>> spark.sql("""
... SELECT t1.group_id,sum((t2.timestamp_value - t1.timestamp_value)) as duration
... FROM
... (SELECT unix_timestamp(timestamp) as timestamp_value,group_id,rownum FROM table1 WHERE state = 'unhealthy') t1
... LEFT JOIN
... (SELECT unix_timestamp(timestamp) as timestamp_value,group_id,rownum FROM table1) t2
... ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id
... AND t1.rownum = t2.rownum - 1
... group by t1.group_id
... """).show()
+--------+--------+
|group_id|duration|
+--------+--------+
|  000001|       9|
+--------+--------+
```

the sample dateset had unhealthy data for group_id `00001` only. but this solution works for cases other group_ids with unhealthy state.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way (may be not optimal) is:

1. Map to `[K,V]` with GROUP_NUMBER as the Key K
2. Use `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`, so you will have all data for every single group in the same partition and have them sorted by `TIMESTAMP`. Detailed explanation how it works is in this answer: [Pyspark: Using repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions with multiple sort Critiria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918342/pyspark-using-repartitionandsortwithinpartitions-with-multiple-sort-critiria)
3. And finally use `mapPartitions` to get an iterator over sorted data in single partition, so you could easily find the answer you needed. (explanation for `mapPartitions`: [How does the pyspark mapPartitions function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741714/how-does-the-pyspark-mappartitions-function-work))